# /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp does not send mail using Laravel on macOS

Tags: php, laravel, macos, smtp, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project that I want to send emails with. I develop it on macOS and I want to test it, but it does not work, but won't give any errors. (I replaced sensitive data with `********`)

*.env*

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=********@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

> Note: I validated those settings, I also tested other working SMTP settings. So it's not a configuration issue in this file

*mail.php*

```php
/// ...

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mail'),

/// ...

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'mail',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

/// ...

    ],

/// ...

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
            resource_path('views/emails'),
        ],
    ],

/// ...
```

*MailController.php*

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{

    public function testMail(Request $request)
    {
        $email = '********@live.com';
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Test mail'
        ];

        Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.testMail'], $data,
            function ($message) use ($email, $data) {
                $message->to($email)
                ->subject($data['title']);
        });

        $response = [
            'error' => 0,
            'to' => $email,
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
}
```

> Note: There is a blade template containing only HTML for test purposes at *resources/views/emails/testMail.blade.php*. I also added the appropriate GET-route.

When I access the endpoint in Postman, I get

```json
{
    "error": 0,
    "to": "********@live.com",
    "data": {
        "title": "Test mail"
    }
}
```

Little Snitch popped up, asking if I want to allow */usr/libexec/postfix/smtp* to access `smtp.gmail.com`, so I know the call goes through. I gave the process all rights to access any server and retried, but the mail will never reach my destination.

Yes, I checked the SPAM folder. Yes, I checked other credentials. Yes I tested manual delivery between both accounts. Yes, I tested with Little Snitch disabled, entirely. Yes, I checked the laravel.log and it reveals nothing.

I noticed, that I won't get any error from Laravel when I put in wrong information in the *.env* file (except when I change `MAIL_MAILER`).

How can I get the output from the SMTP process to find out what the issue is? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Check with Charles app. At least you can determine where the error is.

Comment: @MarekH I installed Wireshark and use the filter `tcp.port == 465 || udp.port == 465`. While I fetch data when I send a mail with [SinriMailTextPost](https://apps.apple.com/sa/app/sinrimailtextpost/id1471499833?mt=12), I don't capture any packages when I run my Laravel code with the same SMTP credentials. When I filter for the IP (`ip.addr == 64.233.184.108`) from the working case when I use SinriMailTextPost, there is no connection in Wireshark on that IP when I run my Laravel code, but Little Snitch reports access to _live-com.olc.protection.outlook.com_ and _gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com_.

Comment: Have you tried with non outlook email address (try multiple)? I think it's blocked. https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/emails-blocked-for-emails-going-to-outlok-com-hotmail-com.84643/

Comment: @MarekH Yes, I have tried with AWS emails, web.de emails, etc. (sending / receiving, all combinations possible). As said, all deliveries succeed using SinriMailTextPost, but `/usr/libexec/postfix/smtp` does not even send packages that I could capture with Wireshark. I start to believe I have spotted a bug in smtp that requires some exotic circumstances that I provide, because this is a developer machine with a lot of stuff installed. How can I dig deeper, please? I need this to work locally before I deploy the code on AWS.